# <base href="/"> not being respected (I think) by some browser

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an angular 10 app. It works great in Chrome, FF, Edge, and Explorer (when I test it).
I however have some errors in my log where users are trying to get paths such as

```
/details/polyfills-es5.1e34e0ed5404808cc3ff.js
```

They should be getting

```
/polyfills-es5.1e34e0ed5404808cc3ff.js
```

I do have sub pages such as `/details/123123` which users can visit and my best guess to what is happening is that users are linking directly to such a page and then a browser is not respecting the `<base href="/">` tag and trying to get the library files using a relative url path in the `/details` folder.

I think this would be solved if all the auto generated tags started with `/`, such as `src="/runtime-es2015.409e6590615fb48d139f.js"` instead of being naked.

But I don't know.

As it is now the autogenerated script tags look like this.

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.409e6590615fb48d139f.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.409e6590615fb48d139f.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.1e34e0ed5404808cc3ff.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.e4131590861f7fffa93e.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.6531bbbed67e7d5e649c.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.6531bbbed67e7d5e649c.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
```

Any suggestions as to what I might do or try?

**Update 1.**
I'm quite sure this is the issue now as I can reproduce the same error locally if I try to navigate to `https://localhost:5000/details/runtime-es2015.409e6590615fb48d139f.js`. I just don't understand how this is happening on the live site as I can only get this by specifically entering that url in the browser, I can't think of any way to produce that problem without trying to go directly to that url. I've tried all the above mentioned browsers and refreshed and pasted links to all parts of the website but everything works as expected. I doubt that someone is sitting and pasting that specific url manually just to mess with my logs.. but I woulden't deem it impossible.

**Update 2.**
Added some more logging to get the offending User Agent. It's the facebook crawler doing this.

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

I've contacted facebook about this, not sure how much they care.